# Switching from WebView to other views in Android

Tags: java, android, webview

I am developing a photo sharing app for Android.  I have a web site that I want the Android to get `WebViews` for most of it, but I want the android to have a native home screen rather than the web site homescreen.

As of right now, I open a `WebView` for login (this is needed because i must login with twitter) but after that I want the android to go to its own native home screen rather that the web site home screen.

I have tried using the `shouldOverrideUrl()` method to no avail.  Is it even possible to program and android app to switch from the `WebView` at a given url?

Answer (score 0):

Just create a method to check for the URLs to catch. Then make it not call the URL and open the home screen.